# Why don't the new recruits show any facial expression when Varga attacks them?

Tags: underworld, underworld-blood-wars

In [*Underworld Blood Wars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underworld:_Blood_Wars), Varga started shooting all the recruits who witnessed the cage fight between him and Selene.

[image: Ranks of recruits]

But there are no facial expressions on the new recruits, this scene looks a lot like this [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11/why-the-stoic-acting-style-in-2001-space-odyssey).

Actually this scene lasts for a few seconds which is enough for us to notice stoic facial expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He's using his vampire speed. The bloodlings are too young to have developed super speed and can't react very quickly.

<sub>*Just like this movie did to the audience.*</sub>

You can see that it takes seconds for Vagra to kill everybody, only one really has time to run and ***panic***. Hilariously.

[image]

16 seconds at slow speed. Speed it up on youtube to 1.5x speed, and it seems more natural, and we see normal speed reactions. It's really should be about 1.75x speed.

**They look stoic because they are stunned and have not processed the situation yet.**

Sidenote, you can't expect nameless extras to have the same emotional range of paid actors.

Comment: First link is dead :/